# SDL2 - Fullscreen not stretching image

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have a SDL2 game project written in C that has a fullscreen feature, using

```
SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP)
```

Drawing was then allowed on all the fullscreen'd window surface.

However, I since switched from directly rendering into the window to rendering into a texture that gets then rendered on-screen.

```
void initGFX(void) {
  // (SNIP)
  framebuffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_UNKNOWN, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT); // WINDOW_WIDTH and _HEIGHT are constants, the non-fullscreen window having these sizes.
  // (SNIP)
}

void renderPresent(void) {
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL); // renderer has "SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE"
  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, framebuffer, NULL, NULL);
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
  SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, framebuffer);
}
```

This doesn't cause any graphical errors when in windowed mode, but in fullscreen the texture is rendered 1:1 on the top-left corner.

SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN doesn't allow drawing on the whole screen even with SDL_SetWindowDisplayMode to have .w and .h match the desktop resolution.

Comment: you may need to scale the image.

Comment: @YOU SDL2 is supposed to scale everything for you if you request a virtual resolution different than the physical resolution (because changing the hardware's resolution sucks). I admit I don't know the details, though.